# Bean shell scripting to check if response A or B is present in response text in jmeter

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter, beanshell

How to verify if response A or B is present in response text in jmeter using beanshell script assertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) provides the following pre-defined variables:

- `ResponseData` - byte array, contains parent sampler response
- `Failure` - boolean, indicates whether assertion (and the sampler(s) in scope) is/are successful or not
- `FailureMessage` - a String which can be used to provide a custom error message

Example code which checks if response contains `A` and if doesn't - the sampler gets failed.

```
String response = new String(ResponseData);

Failure = !response.contains("A");
FailureMessage = "Response didn't contain A";
```

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: Thanks but how to use OR in the code like response.contains("A") or response.contains("B")

Comment: Something like `if (response.contains("A") || response.contains("B")) { //do what you need }`. See [Summary of Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) for details

Comment: Thanks  a lot it worked